How to implement the Preferences menu in Toga application?
I tried like this, but when I access the menu, the Preferences item is not enabled :
class Application(toga.App):
  def startup(self):
    # ... build UI here
    self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.formal_name)
    self.main_window.content = MainBox
    self.main_window.show()  
    
  def preferences(self):
    # Create a new window for the preferences
    pref_window = toga.Window(title="Preferences")
        
    # Create a preferences window layout
    pref_box = toga.Box(style=Pack(direction=COLUMN, padding=10))

    # Example preferences settings (could be text inputs, toggles, etc.)
    theme_label = toga.Label("Choose Theme:", style=Pack(padding=(0, 5)))
    theme_selection = toga.Selection(items=["Light", "Dark"])

    notification_label = toga.Label("Enable Notifications:", style=Pack(padding=(0, 5)))
    notification_toggle = toga.Switch()

    # Add widgets to the box
    pref_box.add(theme_label, theme_selection, notification_label, notification_toggle)

    # Set the content of the preferences window
    pref_window.content = pref_box
    pref_window.show() 


In the current version of Toga (0.4.5), you'll have to enable the menu item and attach an action to it, using the properties of the Command object.
In the next version of Toga, the Preferences/Settings command will no longer be added by default, but there will be an API to add it yourself.

You mean to add my own Preferences menu item, or I can add it in some way to replace the existing one ? How can I access the existing Preferences menu item ?

In Toga 0.4.5 you can find it by looping over App.commands while checking the text property of each command. In the next version of Toga there will be an easier way.
